# unit testing libgdx with using gdx functionallity

Tags: libgdx

I have a runnig libgdx project, which I would like to unittest.

I don't know how to use gdx funtionality in a unittest, which I do not like to mock. I get errors using libgdx framework in my unittest.

I get the following error with following code (Texture texture = new Texture("ship.png");):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)
```

Code :

```java
public class MapDrawerTest extends ApplicationAdapter {

    MapDrawer mapDrawer;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        Schiff schiff = new Schiff();
        World world = new World(100,100);
        mapDrawer = new MapDrawer(world, schiff);
        batch =  Mockito.mock(SpriteBatch.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void drawFeld() {

        Feld feld1 = new Feld(new Feldkoordinate(1,1), Feldtyp.LANDPALMEN);

        Texture texture = new Texture("ship.png");
        List<Texture> textures = new ArrayList<Texture>();
        textures.add(texture);
        feld1.addTexture(new FeldTexture(textures,60));

        mapDrawer.drawFeld(batch, feld1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the headless backend to your dependencies and initialize it before your Unit Tests run.

[This guide](http://manabreak.eu/java/2016/10/21/unittesting-libgdx.html) explains all necessary steps.